# How to insert a fragment without removing the already existing ones

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add a fragment that contains what I need in every header of my files. But when I use th:insert or th:replace it deletes the already existing elements in the place where I inserted it.

fragments/normal.html

```html
<html>
   <head th:fragment="head">
      <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" href="../public/css/main.css" />
   </head>
<html>
```

index.html

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="/index" th:insert="fragments/normal :: head">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/index.css}" href="../public/css/index.css" />
   </head>
</html>
```

I expected this:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" href="../public/css/main.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/index.css}" href="../public/css/index.css" />

   </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just go with `th:replace`:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="/index">
   <head>
      <div th:replace="fragments/normal :: head"></div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/index.css}" href="../public/css/index.css" />
   </head>
</html>
```